# Get name of current processing folder in Grunt?

Tags: javascript, css, npm, gruntjs

I would like to get the name of the current folder that Grunt is processing so that I can include page-specific CSS inline with something like grunt-contrib-html-build.

Example folder structure:

```
app
 - home
   - home.html
   - home.module.js
   - home.controller.js
 - help
   - help.html
   - etc
 - styles
   - home.css
   - help.css
```

Then during build I would want to include /styles/%current_dir_name%.css inline which for home.html would inline /styles/home.css and for help.html it would include /styles/help.css

Perhaps I'm going about this the wrong way, I've tried a few ways in grunt and I can't seem to get this data.

Comment: If I go inside of buld-html.js I can get this under grunt.files.forEach(function (file) > file.src.forEach(function (src) > src.match(/(?!.+\/).+(?=\.)/g). I'm just not sure how to access that in the grunt file, as I don't want to modify the plugin.

Comment: You won't be able to access that without modifying the plugin, or writing your own wrapper around that plugin. The data simply isn't exposed outside of that module.